# Static lambda in class initialization

Tags: c++, lambda, initialization

I'm trying to make the initialization of a 
lambda expression in class. 
The pseudo code could be like this

```
class A{
  //stuff..
  static constexpr auto lambda = [] (unsigned char element){//stuff..};

};
```

When i tried to compile i get this error message

```
 error: ‘constexpr const A::<lambda(unsigned char)> A::get_range’, declared using local type ‘const A::<lambda(unsigned char)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
 static constexpr auto lambda = [](unsigned char element){
```

How can i do this in class initialization? 
Thank you indeed and sorry for the English.

Comment: what version of c++ are you using constexpr lambda are since c++17

Comment: I'm using c++11

Comment: I cannot reproduce with neither C++11, nor C++17.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lambda as a static member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725881/lambda-as-a-static-member)

Comment: If i use c++17 compiles so @Tyker thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of C++17, lambdas can be `constexpr`, ([P0170R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0170r1.pdf)) this is however not supported on all compilers yet, so depending on your compiler, it might or might not work (g++ supports this since version 7, the intel compiler will feature it from 19.0 on).

As a workaround, you can use `decltype` to implement a `static const` lambda member

```
auto lambda = [](unsigned char element){};
class A{
   //stuff
   static const decltype(lambda) a;
};
const decltype(lambda) A::a{lambda};
```